Deleted components still showing up when trying to uninstall package
I'm trying to uninstall a managed package, but in the list of problems with uninstall I get these few items that I've already deleted but are still showing up as a problem. When I click the links it provides it takes me to a page that says there's a permissions issue, but I know I already deleted it. I'm thinking it's just stuck in a recycle bin of sorts somewhere. Any ideas?


When you delete a field or object, it remains in the org for a period of time (currently 15 days) so you can undelete it.
If you deleted an object, switch to Salesforce Classic, then navigate to Setup > Create > Objects, and scroll to the bottom. You'll find deleted objects here. Permanently erase them to continue.
If you deleted custom fields, you'll find them in Setup > Create > Objects > Object Name (Classic) or Setup > Object Manager > Object Name > Fields and Relationships > Deleted Fields. Permanently erase them to continue.
Once you've these objects and fields, you'll be able to uninstall the package.

Thank you, I was able to permanently delete the object and now I can uninstall.

@RyanNeel You're welcome!

Even though you deleted the custom object or relationship field, there is still a reference to it somewhere in your Salesforce org.
Try removing it from the recycle bin as well. You can do that by performing the following steps:

Click the app launcher.
Search Recycle Bin.
Manually delete the fields that are getting referenced.

